# Using @availity with react-scripts: "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, react-scripts

When I try to import a component from **[`@availity`](https://availity.github.io/availity-react/#installation)**, I get a compiler error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@availity/form/src/Checkbox.js
SyntaxError: /home/admin/node_modules/@availity/form/src/Checkbox.js: 
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (29:5):

  27 |
  28 |   return (
> 29 |     <FormGroup
     |     ^
  30 |       for={inputId}
  31 |       className={groupClassName}
  32 |       check

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) 
to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) 
to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I've tried for hours, adding the requested presets to my babel config via `package.json`, `.babelrc` , `babel.config.json`, deleting `node_modules + yarn.lock`, installing/uninstall various packages, and so on.

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form } from '@availity/form'

const App = () => {
  return null
}

export default App
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@availity/form": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },

  ...

}
```

**Software:**

- **ubuntu 20.04** running in a vm
- **node 16.3.0**
- **yarn 1.22.5**

I tried moving the `node_modules` source for `@availity/form` into my project's src, then importing from it directly, and it runs just fine:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form } from './@availity/form'

const App = () => {
  return null
}

export default App
```